# Cancel an HTTP GET request from Firefox Extension

Tags: http, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a firefox extension that listens to "http-on-modify-request" and inspects all GET requests coming from firefox.  I'd like to be able to cancel the request (say return a fail code to the page) or modify the URI of the request but can't seem to do it.  the nsiHttpChannel object just doesn't allow it - for instance

```
delete httpChannel;
```

or reseting to an empty request

```
httpChannel = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
```

don't work (and you can't modify the URI).

So how do you both *intercept* and *modify* http GET requests in a firefox extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`delete httpChannel;` just deletes the variable, sort of like saying `httpChannel = undefined;`. The request itself is unchanged. Similarly, your second idea just sets the variable to point at a new nsIHttpChannel instance, but the old request is still unchanged.

To modify the request, use its properties and methods. See [nsIHttpChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel) or [nsIChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIChannel) or [nsIRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIRequest). As you say, you can't modify the URI so you might want to cancel it (see below) and replace it with a new one. I'm not sure exactly how to do that but I imagine one of those three pages has the answer.

To cancel it, use [nsIRequest.cancel()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIRequest#cancel%28%29)